# Map of projects

Tags: google-maps

My company is doing IT and solar/wind power projects
And i would like to show it on a map
When people click they should go to page with full project information

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [GMap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) module

The GMap package consists of the following modules:

**GMap:** provides the GMap API, integration with Views and Location, and GMap macros.

**GMap Location:** Provides a map of all a site's nodes and a map of all of the site users.

**GMap Taxonomy:** Allows you to display different map markers based on taxonomy of a specific node.

**GMap Macro Builder:** Provides a GUI for building "macros" (a text-based way of describing arbitrary GMaps).

Find addresses on GMAP #1921872: [Find address on map button - 7.x only](https://www.drupal.org/node/1921872)